# How many omegas are there in $\large f_{\varepsilon_0}$?

Tags: number-theory, functions, ordinals

For a description look at fast growing hierarchy at wikipedia.
$\large f_{\varepsilon_0}$ is not defined any more, it is a power
tower of omegas, but how many omegas ?

I found a defition

$$\large f_{\varepsilon_0}(n) = \large f_{{\omega}^{...\omega}}(n)$$ with $n-1$ omega's

but it would be more natural to take $n$ omegas.

Which of these definitions is standard ?

If it would be the first one, $\large f_{\varepsilon_0}(3)$ would "only"
be $\large f_{\omega^{\omega}}(3)$.

Comment: I am looking for the diagonalization, the fundamental sequence.

Comment: Peter, $\varepsilon_0$ is the limit of the sequence defined as follows, $\alpha_0=0$, $\alpha_{n+1}=\omega^\alpha_n$. So you get $0,1,\omega,\omega^\omega,\omega^{\omega^\omega}$ and so on. So the power tower is of length $\omega$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The question is about what convention to use. For $\alpha$ limit, once we settle on a strictly increasing $\alpha_n\to\alpha$, we define $f_\alpha(n)=f_{\alpha_n}(n)$. For $\epsilon_0$, three natural options come to mind: (1) $0,1,\omega,\omega^\omega,\dots$, so $f_{\epsilon_0}(3)=f_{\omega^\omega}(3)$. (2) $1,\omega,\omega^\omega,\omega^{\omega^\omega},\dots$, so $f_{\epsilon_0}(3)=f_{\omega^{\omega^\omega}}(3)$. (3) The same sequence, starting at $\omega$, which leads to yet a different value for $f_{\epsilon_0}(3)$. (Cont.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila (And, of course, there are yet other, perhaps less natural, options.) The question is which of all these options is the agreed upon convention. I like option (1), $\zeta_0=0$, $\zeta_{n+1}=\omega^{\zeta_n}$, since we have that $I\Sigma_{k+1}$-provably total recursive functions are eventually dominated by some $f_\alpha$ with $\alpha<\zeta_{k+1}$, and these $f_\alpha$ are provably total in this theory. But, of course, there may be stronger reasons for choosing a different sequence that experts on ordinal analysis may have agreed on. (Or perhaps there is no "official" convention.)

Comment: @Andres, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It largely depends on the definition of the fundamental sequence.

Almost all definitions use $\varepsilon_0[n+1]=\omega^{\varepsilon_0[n]}$, however, there are two conventions for $\varepsilon_0[0]$:

- $\varepsilon_0[0]=0$, [Gallier 1991]
- $\varepsilon_0[0]=1$, [Prӧmel, et al., 1991]

This is because it is natural to think as $\varepsilon_0[0]$ as a tower of zero $\omega$s and thus of $\varepsilon_0[n]$ as a tower of $n$ $\omega$s, but on the other hand, form one you can still go one step down, since $\omega^0=1$.